# Lift: Comet component not found / Class not found

Tags: scala, lift

For my first steps into Lift I just started with [this tutorial](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-2.html) but it won't work for me. Instead of the simple chat app I only get these two exceptions:

```
Error processing snippet: comet
Reason: Comet Component not found
```

and

```
Error processing snippet: ChatIn
Reason: Class Not Found
```

Here is the directory structure of my compiled webapp:

```
target/chat-1.0-SNAPSHOT/
├── index.html
├── META-INF
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   └── code
    │       ├── comet
    │       │   ├── Chat$$anonfun$lowPriority$1.class
    │       │   ├── Chat.class
    │       │   ├── ChatServer$$anonfun$lowPriority$1.class
    │       │   ├── ChatServer.class
    │       │   └── ChatServer$.class
    │       └── snippet
    │           ├── ChatIn$$anonfun$render$1.class
    │           ├── ChatIn.class
    │           └── ChatIn$.class
    ├── lib
    │   ├── activation-1.1.jar
    │   ├── commons-codec-1.4.jar
    │   ├── commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
    │   ├── derby-10.7.1.1.jar
    │   ├── h2-1.2.147.jar
    │   ├── htmlparser-1.2.1.jar
    │   ├── joda-time-1.6.2.jar
    │   ├── lift-actor_2.9.0-2.4-M3.jar
    │   ├── lift-common_2.9.0-2.4-M3.jar
    │   ├── lift-db_2.9.0-2.4-M3.jar
    │   ├── lift-json_2.9.0-2.4-M3.jar
    │   ├── lift-mapper_2.9.0-2.4-M3.jar
    │   ├── lift-proto_2.9.0-2.4-M3.jar
    │   ├── lift-util_2.9.0-2.4-M3.jar
    │   ├── lift-webkit_2.9.0-2.4-M3.jar
    │   ├── mail-1.4.4.jar
    │   ├── paranamer-2.3.jar
    │   ├── scala-compiler-2.9.0.jar
    │   ├── scala-library-2.9.0.jar
    │   ├── scalap-2.9.0.jar
    │   └── slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
    └── web.xml
```

But as you can see, there are the compiled .class files for Chat, ChatServer and ChatIn, so what's wrong?

Comment: For help on issues like this, please see: https://app.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/comet_issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please bring this question to the Lift Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb

It's likely that your Boot.scala doesn't contain the correct information, but without the source, it's tough to figure out the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am new to Lift and just finished Chapter 2 of the mentioned tutorial. There is no Boot.scala. Is it required?

Comment: Thanks again for this hint. I found the Boot.scala at the github project of the tutorial but I can't remember that they mentioned it in chapter 2 of the tutorial.